# Need to return only duplicate records by SSN only in combined query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We are currently migrating from a progress db to sql server and I am producing some reports that pull data from each.  One of these reports needs to find customers who have more than one record existing by their SSN, and I'm just not getting anywhere with it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    [SSN]
    ,[Loan Number]
    ,[Last Name]
    ,field 4
    ,field 5
    ...

FROM
(SELECT
    [SSN]
    ,[Loan Number]
    ,[Last Name]
    ,field 4
    ,field 5
    ...

FROM openquery(progressdb, 
'SELECT
    "SSN"
    ,"Loan Number"
    ,"Last Name"
    ,field 4
    ,field 5
    ...') as prog1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    [SSN]
    ,[Loan Number]
    ,[Last Name]
    ,field 4
    ,field 5
    ...
    ) as combined
```

Comment: try to aggregate by SSN and use the HAVING COUNT(*) > 1. Also do you want to find duplicates in one DB both or ignoring the duplicates between the new and old DB?

Comment: I see two MAJOR issues here. The first is that you should normalize your data. That way you don't store data over and over like that. Columns like Names, SSN [ack], etc should be in a separate table. The second, far bigger issue is storing SSN. From what you posted it looks like it might even be in clear text. Sensitive and personal data should ALWAYS be encrypted.

Comment: I'm not the DBA I'm just running queries.  As far as normalization, they are in separate tables I'm just simplifying what I enter here.  The actual query is pulling a lot of fields from a lot of different tables.  I'm not going to go into our encryption/security practices as it is not germane to the question.

Answer (score 0):

OK I've got what I need.  I didn't get all the way to what I needed in a query, but a group on SSN in SSRS with a show/hide based on expression of =iif(count(Fields!Loan_Number.Value) = 1, true, false) got me where I need to be.